# Determining the smoothness of the space

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

I need to determine whether the following spaces are smooth.

1) $S=F^{-1}(0)$, $F(x,y,z)=3xy+x^2+z$

2) $g: \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2, g(s,t)=(3s,s^2-2t,s^3+t^2)$

Can someone please give a sketch of how to do these kind of problems? I just need some clue, the text I am using does not give many examples.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smoothness of the first space is a special case of the [preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem).  For a smooth function $F : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$, we say that a point $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a *regular value* if for every $(x,y,z) \in F^{-1}(c) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, the derivative at $(x,y,z)$ is nonzero.  Now the preimage theorem says that if $c$ is a regular value, then $F^{-1}(c)$ is a (smooth) submanifold.  For your example, you should just check that $0$ is a regular value.

The second is not a space, just a function, and it is smooth because it is polynomial.